# How to log errors in dataflow adf of parallel sources

Tags: azure, microsoft-dynamics, azure-data-lake

I have to do some data engineering by reading `manifest.cdm.json` files from datalake.
add pipeline run id column and push to sql database.

I have one `json list file` which have required parameter to read `CDM json file` in source of dataflow.

**Previous Approach**: I used `Foreach` and passed parameter to `dataflow` with `single activity` then error capturing. But use of Dataflow with `for each` costs too much..

**Current Approch**: I mannually created Dataflow with all cdm files. But here I'm not able to capture error. If any source got error all dataflow activity fails. and If I select skip error in dataflow activity I'm not getting any error.

So what should be the approch to get errors from current approch.

[image: AZURE DATAFLOW]

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the error using `set variable` activity in Azure Data Factory.

Use below expression to capture the error message using Set Variable activity:

`@activity('Data Flow1').Error.message`

[image]

Later you can store the error message in blob storage for future reference using `copy activity`. In below example we are saving error message in .csv file using DelimitedText dataset.

[image]